# Efficient way of using proguard in android

Tags: android, proguard, decompiling

I am trying to prevent the app from being de-compiled and thus getting exposed. I know there is proguard which I can use to convert the java files to  .smali files. But my question is, how secure are these .smali files?

When I did R&D on that, I got some results that .smali files can be converted back to java files. Is that true? Or else what is the best way to prevent the apk from decompiling?  My app includes lot of financial details, so at any cost I should not be able to reveal them to the outside world or at least I am trying to make it very difficult to decompile it.

**Note**: I have already did lot of work on getting the working of proguard

Your answer would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proguard is built in to later versions of the Android SDK. You just point to proguard.cfg and it will be used during release. I assume you know this bit.

Proguard is not related to smali. In the end all these tools output working bytecode and you can always recompile bytecode. Can't stop that. What proguard can do is rename all the symbols in your code so that the result is very hard to understand.

If you mean you are storing sensitive info in string literals in your app then don't do that. These can't be obfuscated or else your app wouldn't work. They are always visible as literals in the byte code.